# Hover link-menu not working on IE 11, pseudo classes ignored

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, pseudo-class

i'm trying to do a menu like [this one](http://codepen.io/sebastianekstrom/pen/jDmKo) for a project in the making but IE 11 keeps ignoring the pseudo classes.

```
 +<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
```

etc...

I have `+<!doctype html>` because if i remove the + the elements get disorted in chrome for some reason, and altough i've tried removing it because from what i've heard ie forces itself into quircks mode thus not being able to handle pseudo classes doing so does not solve the problem, even with `<!doctype html>` ie ignores the css and then chrome gets it's view all messed up.

here's a fiddle with the code copy-pasted from what i'm doing. if you remove the `#botao span:after` you'll see how it renders on IE

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/americanjoel/YE3p7/)

i've only tested the code on chrome, firefox and ie so far and i tried javascript to detect ie and hide the menu and show a different one but it also didn't work, and older browsers won't be a problem because css3 transforms won't occur leaving the first links in the place (or so i suspect. have to test it later on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo class works in IE if you give the anchor tag a reference target. For example:

```
<span class="hoverlink"><a href=#>Hover over me</a></span>

.hoverlink a, .hoverlink a:visited, .hoverlink a:link{color:red;}
.hoverlink a:hover{color:green;}
```

Try putting in an "href" and see all the difference it makes in IE!

If you need an element other than the A tag to support pseudo class you'll have to use a doctype. And yes, it breaks the layout for some old IEs not because it enters quirks mode. Quite on the contrary, it leaves quirks mode, and "tries" to conform to standards and miserably fails.

Comment: i tried modiffing the fiddle like you sugested but something interesting happened, the menu kept blinking on mousehover.
I'm fairly sure it's not that i have bad code somewhere since it displayed as it should on firefox but it really is a transform problem, when i removed the transform line in #div:hover span it displayed the menu without transforming it tough. 

Until i can find a way or some one has a better way of going around it i guess the only way that code is going to be rendered as it should is going to be on chrome and safari

Comment: Could you post a fiddle and specify whether you were using doctype, and which browser you tested it on? Try giving the hover item a solid background color and set its display mode to "block" instead of the implicit "inline".

Comment: [FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/americanjoel/YE3p7/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/americanjoel/YE3p7/1/) I posted the fiddle up on the question but i'll re-post it. I was using the doctype as stated above, but that doesn't seem to be the issue since on the fiddle even without such markings on ie it doesen't display as it should. I tested it on chrome 32, IE 11 and firefox 26

Comment: The posted code is not working in my IE without doctype. Instead of writing #botao:hover, use #botao a:hover. Also if you have many elements with the same ID, use a class instead.

Comment: For me it doesn't work at all, even if i use doctype, use classes and use  .botao a:hover. IE doesn't seem to support this kind of transforms, alto ugh it supports 3Dtransforms and content: attr(x). I had to remove the transforming on IE and firefox by removing rotateX( 90deg ) on hover since i couldn't find IE by javascript and have it disable or override that transform on hover (i tried a script found in here http://jsfiddle.net/9zxvE/383/ and changed so instead of output i'd have 'if (isIE==true) { $('#botao').hover(function{.css('transform', 'rotateX( 0deg )')});'